# how to compare variables from api call, and the condition is met but it still not giving any output or error, program completes

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython-2.7

I want to reference two variables in if condition

```
def remedialIssue(self, branch, issue_id, new_status):
    AppBranch = request.get("/rest/api/latest/issue/" + str(issue_id), params=querystring, contentType='application/json')
    appbranch = json.loads(AppBranch.response)
    appbranch = u" {0}".format(appbranch['fields']['customfield_1000'])
    appbranch = str(appbranch)
    branch = str(branch)
    print(appbranch)
    print(branch)
    if appbranch == branch:
        print "error"
```

branch is passed from external app GUI which calls this function but even if the condition is met, it is not giving any output or error, just completes program.

Comment: It looks like you _are_ comparing two variables in an if condition. Please be more specific in you question, and mention errors or unexpected behavior, if relevant to your question.

Comment: @nikolas-stevenson-molnar — yes I am comparing two variables, but it is not executing even if condition is met, just exists without any output or error

Comment: Ok, please add that to your question. Also, it would be useful to have example values for `branch` and `appbranch`.

Comment: @nikolas-stevenson-molnar -branch will be with data as release and appbranch can be any branch name like rel-hotfix etc

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that when `branch = 'release'` and `appbranch = 'rel-hotfix'`, you're not getting any output from your print statement?

Comment: You are missing parentheses on line 3 of your example (I tried editing, but a single character edit is not allowed for an editor).

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the `if` statement and inspected the values? Are they really different, or perhaps something you're not expecting? Alternatively, have you tried printing them both?

Comment: Yes when I print both the variables before if condition, it prints and program completes, where it actually met a if condition, but just program completes printing two variables before if condition

Comment: Yes appbranch is resolved to rel-hotfix from api response, branch is passed with release as word

Comment: It’s basically doing a jira query and getting the appbranch name and if the branch which is being passed as input from external app is same as appbranch in jira ticket , then do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition tests that `appbranch` and `branch` are equal. Since you are placing a space in front of `appbranch`, this seems unlikely:

```
u" {0}".format(...)
```

Unless `branch` also starts with a space?